# Adding days to locale specific dates using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-parsing

I'm trying to use **moment-with-locales.min.js** to add (or subtract) days to a locale specific date. What I have are textboxes which contain dates formatted to specific locales. When the user updates one, it resets all of the others adding a specified number of days. However, I can't seem to get moment.js to manipulate the date based on anything other than en-US, so the dates are way off.

I've tried several variations using this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rwwL60f/3/)

```
var d = new moment('11/08/2014').locale('en-GB'); //August 11, 2014
alert(d.locale()); //returns en-gb

d.add("days",1).format('L');
//d.add("days",1).locale('en-GB').format('L');
alert(d); //returns November 09, 2014 instead of 12/08/2014

//note, the format is incorrect as well, should be returning short format
```

I'm certain I'm using it incorrectly, so any advice would be welcome.

Comment: `new moment('11/08/2014').locale('en-GB');` is parsed as `Sun Nov 09 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)` not Aug 11, 2004. So it's reading `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: @Halcyon yes, but afaik en-GB has date in format dd/MM/YYYY so it should parse it correctly..

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect as well. Maybe the `.locale` call comes too late? I'm not familiar enough with momentjs.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/665, you need to define L token for parser. At the same time, define locale before you start parsing. So the final code is

```
moment.locale('en-gb');
var d = new moment('11/08/2014', 'L'); //August 11, 2014
alert(d.locale()); //returns en-gb

d.add("days", 1);
alert(d.format('L')); //returns 12/8/2014
```

http://jsfiddle.net/omnbgk5s/2